# Realm messes with Android data binding

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, android-databinding

I have an app that builds OK but as soon as I make one of my classes Realm-aware by either @RealmClass/RealmModel or RealmObject I get a ton of errors like those below.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

`e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\AccountsmoduleBinding.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
  protected AccountsmoduleBinding(DataBindingComponent _bindingComponent, View _root,
                                  ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class AccountsmoduleBinding
w: C:\Dane.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jre7\1.1.4-2\272a21c30432c943d618008fbbd34762eb0d6c8a\kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.1.4-2.jar: kotlin-stdlib-jre7 is deprecated. Please use kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 instead
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\AccountsmoduleBinding.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot, @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                                                                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class AccountsmoduleBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\AccountsmoduleBinding.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class AccountsmoduleBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\AccountsmoduleBinding.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class AccountsmoduleBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\AllaccountsmoduleBinding.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
  protected AllaccountsmoduleBinding(DataBindingComponent _bindingComponent, View _root,
                                     ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class AllaccountsmoduleBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\AllaccountsmoduleBinding.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot, @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                                                                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class AllaccountsmoduleBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\AllaccountsmoduleBinding.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class AllaccountsmoduleBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\AllaccountsmoduleBinding.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class AllaccountsmoduleBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\AnotherfragmentLayoutBinding.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
  protected AnotherfragmentLayoutBinding(DataBindingComponent _bindingComponent, View _root,
                                         ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class AnotherfragmentLayoutBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\AnotherfragmentLayoutBinding.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot, @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                                                                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class AnotherfragmentLayoutBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\AnotherfragmentLayoutBinding.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class AnotherfragmentLayoutBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\AnotherfragmentLayoutBinding.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class AnotherfragmentLayoutBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\AppactivationmoduleBinding.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
  protected AppactivationmoduleBinding(DataBindingComponent _bindingComponent, View _root,
                                       ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class AppactivationmoduleBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\AppactivationmoduleBinding.java:126: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot, @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                                                                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class AppactivationmoduleBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\AppactivationmoduleBinding.java:137: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class AppactivationmoduleBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\AppactivationmoduleBinding.java:148: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class AppactivationmoduleBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\BiometryloginmoduleBinding.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
  protected BiometryloginmoduleBinding(DataBindingComponent _bindingComponent, View _root,
                                       ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class BiometryloginmoduleBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\BiometryloginmoduleBinding.java:97: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot, @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                                                                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class BiometryloginmoduleBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\BiometryloginmoduleBinding.java:108: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class BiometryloginmoduleBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\BiometryloginmoduleBinding.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class BiometryloginmoduleBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\ConfirmationmoduleBinding.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
  protected ConfirmationmoduleBinding(DataBindingComponent _bindingComponent, View _root,
                                      ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class ConfirmationmoduleBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\ConfirmationmoduleBinding.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot, @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                                                                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class ConfirmationmoduleBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\ConfirmationmoduleBinding.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class ConfirmationmoduleBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\ConfirmationmoduleBinding.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class ConfirmationmoduleBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\DashboardmoduleaccountsfragmentBinding.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
  protected DashboardmoduleaccountsfragmentBinding(DataBindingComponent _bindingComponent,
                                                   ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class DashboardmoduleaccountsfragmentBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\DashboardmoduleaccountsfragmentBinding.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot, @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                                                                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class DashboardmoduleaccountsfragmentBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\DashboardmoduleaccountsfragmentBinding.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class DashboardmoduleaccountsfragmentBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\DashboardmoduleaccountsfragmentBinding.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
      @Nullable DataBindingComponent component) {
                ^
  symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
  location: class DashboardmoduleaccountsfragmentBinding
e: C:\Dane\Projekty\Livecycle\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\pl\qus\livecycle\databinding\DashboardmoduleBinding.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
  protected DashboardmoduleBinding(DataBindingComponent _bindingComponent, View _root,`

CUT

Gradle plugins:

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android'`

Data class:

`@RealmClass
open class AccountData (
        @PrimaryKey @SerializedName("id")
        var _id : String = "",
        var accountNumber: String = "",
        @SerializedName("type") var _type : String = "",
        var name : String = "",
        var availableFunds: Float = 0f,
        var balance: Float = 0f,
        @SerializedName("currency") var _currency: String = "",
        var ownerName : String = "",
        var interestRate : Float = 0f,
        var sortCode : String = "",
        var iban : String = "",
        var openingDate : String = "",
        var overdraft : Float = 0f,
        var lockedFunds : Float = 0f,
        var creditLimit : Float = 0f,
        var defaultName: String = ""
) : RealmModel {
    var type : AccountType
        get() = AccountType.valueOf(_type)
        set(value) { _type = value.name }`

```
var currency : CurrencyType
    get() = CurrencyType.valueOf(_currency)
    set(value) { _currency = value.name }
```

}

Comment: Please show your gradle plugin order `apply plugin: ...` and also the model class that you are trying to add --- but my wager goes for that you either didn't add a no-args constructor for your RealmObject, or you didn't make it `open`

Comment: You should add `@field:Ignore var type : AccountType`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@RealmClass
open class AccountData (
    ...
) : RealmModel {
    var type : AccountType  // <-- this is not a supported field type
        get() = AccountType.valueOf(_type)
        set(value) { _type = value.name }

var currency : CurrencyType // <-- this is not a supported field type
    get() = CurrencyType.valueOf(_currency)
    set(value) { _currency = value.name }
}
```

You need to mark unsupported "helper" fields with `@Ignore` annotation.

```
@field:Ignore
var type : AccountType  // <-- this is not a supported field type
    get() = AccountType.valueOf(_type)
    set(value) { _type = value.name }

@field:Ignore
var currency : CurrencyType // <-- this is not a supported field type
    get() = CurrencyType.valueOf(_currency)
    set(value) { _currency = value.name }
}
```